# Reduce dimensions of a tensor (to a scalar)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, backpropagation

In:

```
a = torch.tensor([[2.4]])
torch.squeeze(a, 1)
a.size(), a
```

Out:

```
(torch.Size([1, 1]), tensor([[2.4000]]))
```

During computations using `nn.MSELoss`, I got a mismatch of dimensions.
Input had size ([1,1]) and target ([]).
The functions `reshape` and `squeeze` haven't worked.
I would be grateful for a solution, to this embarassingly simple problem. : ]

Edit: there was a simple mistake of not assigning `a=` the squeezed value. Thank You for Your answer.

Comment: Thank You! (I did now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [`torch.squeeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html#torch.squeeze) will not modify input `a`. Either reassign it:

```
a = a.squeeze(1)
```

or use the in-place version of the function [`torch.squeeze_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.squeeze_.html?highlight=squeeze_#torch.Tensor.squeeze_)

```
a.squeeze_(1)
```